# Only Javascript code to show a class without onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I would like some help with one problem that i have with some javascript code.
I have this html element

```
<a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);" href="#" class="bwpb-button test2 bwpb-btnregular" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=&quot;#dd3333&quot;" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=&quot;#0c0c0c&quot;"><i class="undefined"></i>This is a button</a>
```

Which has a classname: test2

below of this button type there is a div with a classname: test1 which has 3 photos.

```
.test1 { visibility: hidden; }
```

with the css style that i wrote above its hidden and i want to make it vissible when i click the button type  to be visible.  I tried the codes below but nothing worked

1st try:

```
#test2:active ~ #test1 { visibility: visible; }
```

2nd try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
         $(".test2").mouseover(function(){
              $(".test1").css("visibility", "visible");
         });
    });
```

I cant put a "onclick" function in the button type  element because its in wordpress and i cant find the index.php that my theme uses.

I have 2 questions.
1) How can i do it without putting a function onclick in the  element?

2) i 've found this code

```
<a href="#something">Show</a>
<div id="something">Bingo!</div>

#something {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#something:target {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

But i cant put any id on the div. Is there any way to add an id to a div with a classname: test1 using javascript and then run the code above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this example https://jsfiddle.net/b20c15sr/

You can use jquery easily for that

```
<div class="test1">
    I am hidden
</div>

<a style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important; background-color: rgb(12, 12, 12);" href="#" class="bwpb-button test2 bwpb-btnregular" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor=&quot;#dd3333&quot;" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor=&quot;#0c0c0c&quot;"><i class="undefined"></i>This is a button</a>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('.test2').click(function(){
        $('.test1').css('visibility', 'visible')
    })

})
</script>
```

Comment: Onclick only not mouseover!

Comment: @KwnstantinosNatsios use the click event then. Check https://jsfiddle.net/b20c15sr/1/

Comment: Is it possible to make it with javascript code please?

Answer (score 1):

As well as using visibility you can also use display: none; Then use the jQuery hide() and show() methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/xpy9ux8u/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").mouseenter(function(){
        $(".hidden").show();
    });

    $("#button").mouseleave(function(){
        $(".hidden").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Onclick only not mouseenter!

Comment: For onclick just use $("#button").click instead of $("#button").mouseenter